# Same circuit for Multiple Asynchronous PRESETs / CLEARs

Tags: digital-logic

I'm using a dual JK flip flop (IC 74109) in my circuit. I want to keep one of the two flip flops cleared initially, and want to preset the other.So, I intend to use the asynchronous preset and clear pins along with standard resistor-capacitor circuit to achieve this. My question is, can I use only A SINGLE R-C circuit to initially trigger BOTH the asynchronous inputs? I know I can ideally, but are there any practical issues?

Comment: how will you handle the input currents?

Comment: the logic inputs or the power inputs? sorry, but didn't quite get what you mean by "handle".